# Detecting if a Windows process AND application is running

Tags: php, windows, process, taskbar, quickbooks

I'm investigating if there is a way to programatically check if a certain process is running as a process (in the list of running exe's) **AND** as an open application (i.e on the taskbar) and take action based on the results.

Also - is there a way to programatically kill a process **OR** a running application?

We are running a WAMP application on this server so ideally i'd like a way to do this using PHP, but am open to whatever will work best.

Any advice?

Comment: I have not seen or heard a php script accessing or being able to view,  or access the currently running application in a users unit. PHP is web programming language if I am not mistaken. PHP is probably not the best choice or not even in the list of choices in your task that you are aiming to do.

Comment: Maybe, that's what i'm trying to confirm - from what i've seen you *can* run cmd line statements from PHP - but whether it's possible to do what i need is another question.

Comment: Since this is tagged QuickBooks - specifically WHAT are you trying to do that involves QuickBooks? Chances are, there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> check if a certain process is running as a process

If you have the tasklist command, sure:

```
// show tasks, redirect errors to NUL (hide errors)
exec("tasklist 2>NUL", $task_list);

print_r($task_list);
```

Then you can kill it, using by matching/extracting the tasknames from the lines.

```
exec("taskkill /F /IM killme.exe 2>NUL");
```

I used that a lot with php-cli. Example:

```
// kill tasks matching
$kill_pattern = '~(helpctr|jqs|javaw?|iexplore|acrord32)\.exe~i';

// get tasklist
$task_list = array();

exec("tasklist 2>NUL", $task_list);

foreach ($task_list AS $task_line)
{
  if (preg_match($kill_pattern, $task_line, $out))
  {
    echo "=> Detected: ".$out[1]."\n   Sending term signal!\n";
    exec("taskkill /F /IM ".$out[1].".exe 2>NUL");
  }
}
```

Comment: Dunno, if you can distinguish in some way, if its in the taskbar - maybe with some 3rd party tool. But you could give the task some name and match exactly that task in your taskkill if active (tasklist).

Comment: Great answer! I was wondering if I can do this check on a different server than the one wamp is running on?

Comment: In case it is not working for you, add `start /B`, i.e., `$task_list = array(); exec("start /B tasklist 2>NUL", $task_list);`. Source: [taskkill from PHP exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853625/taskkill-from-php-exec)