# Create external process and wait 5 seconds kill it in php

Tags: java, php

I want to kill a external process after 5 seconds it created
That process is `javac Hello.java & java Hello`

I figured out a method that is kill process's pid, but samples below cannot get pid.

```
<?php
system('javac Hello.java & java Hello', $retval);
popen('javac Hello.java & java Hello', 'w');
?>
```

I don't understand proc_open() and proc_get_status example in PHP manual.
In my case, how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648304/detecting-if-a-windows-process-and-application-is-running - look at the answer

Comment: tasklist is not effective when server has a lot of work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very clear explanation for how to use proc_open()
https://www.sitepoint.com/proc-open-communicate-with-the-outside-world/

I've done my job for creating an external process to compile , run java program, wait seconds, kill java running process in PHP script.

Here is that script:

```
<?php
/**
    This is a judge script for verifying lab assignment 
    of NTU Civil Engineering Computer Programing with no testdata.
    You can copy, redistribute, or modify it freely.

    Tips:
    It is not necessary to use file already provided.
    Any related file can be uploaded via testdata field.
    Then how to apply specific file uploaded to ./problem/testdata/[item]/[subitem] 
    completely depends on by how the judge file is defined.
 */

// Error report mechanism of this script
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);


// Auto load class definition file that this script will be using.
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include_once($class_name . '.php');
}

class Java_No_Input {

    private $stu_account;
    private $item;
    private $subitem;
    private $main;
    private $dir_name;
    private $status;
    private $solution_output;
    private $student_output;

    private $hookup;

    public function __construct () {

        // Arguments: student account, item, subitem
        $this->stu_account = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
        $this->item = $_SERVER['argv'][2];
        $this->subitem = $_SERVER['argv'][3];

        try {
            // Connect to MySQL database TAFreeDB
            $this->hookup = UniversalConnect::doConnect();                      

            // Create directory to put source codes temporarily
            $this->createDir();

            // Fetch student and solution source from table [item]_[subitem]
            $this->fetchSource();

            // Start judge 
            $this->startJudge();

            // Update judge status
            $this->updateStatus();

            // Remove directory
            $this->removeDir();

            $this->hookup = null;

            exit();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
        }

    }

    public function createDir () {
        $this->dir_name = './process/' . uniqid(time(), true);
        mkdir($this->dir_name);
        mkdir($this->dir_name . '/student');
        mkdir($this->dir_name . '/solution');
    }

    public function removeDir () {
        system('rm -rf ' . $this->dir_name, $retval);
        if ($retval !== 0 ) {
            echo 'Directory can not be removed...';
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function fetchSource () {
        $stmt = $this->hookup->prepare('SELECT main, classname, original_source, ' . $this->stu_account . ' FROM ' . $this->item . '_' . $this->subitem);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ($row['main'] === 'V') {
                $this->main = $row['classname'];
            }
            $student = fopen($this->dir_name . '/student/' . $row['classname'], 'w');
            fwrite($student, $row[$this->stu_account]);
            fclose($student);

            $solution = fopen($this->dir_name . '/solution/' . $row['classname'], 'w');
            fwrite($solution, $row['original_source']);
            fclose($solution);

        }
    }

    public function startJudge () {

        // Solution and student directory whose source is in
        $solution_dir = $this->dir_name . '/solution';
        $student_dir = $this->dir_name . '/student';

        // Compile source code from both solution and student
        $solution_CE = $this->compile($solution_dir);
        if (!empty($solution_CE)) {

            // Configure result that will response to client side
            $error_msg = '<h1>Solution has compiler error</h1>' . '<pre><code>' . $solution_CE . '</code></pre>';
            $this->configureView($error_msg);

            // System error
            $this->status = 'SE';
            return;

        }
        $student_CE = $this->compile($student_dir);
        if (!empty($student_CE)) {

            // Configure result that will response to client side
            $error_msg = '<h1>Your source code has compiler error</h1>' . '<pre><code>' . $student_CE . '</code></pre>';
            $this->configureView($error_msg);

            // Compiler error
            $this->status = 'CE';
            return;

        }

        // Execute source code from both solution and student   
        $solution_RE = $this->execute($solution_dir, 2);
        if (!empty($solution_RE)) {

            // Configure result that will response to client side
            $error_msg = '<h1>Solution has runtime error</h1>' . '<pre><code>' . $solution_RE . '</code></pre>';
            $this->configureView($error_msg);

            // System error
            $this->status = 'SE';
            return;

        }
        $student_RE = $this->execute($student_dir, 2);
        if (!empty($student_RE)) {

            // Configure result that will response to client side
            $error_msg = '<h1>Your source code has runtime error</h1>' . '<pre><code>' . $student_RE . '</code></pre>';
            $this->configureView($error_msg);

            // Runtime error
            $this->status = 'RE';
            return;

        }

        // Compare output from both solution and student
        $this->solution_output = $this->execute($solution_dir, 1);
        $this->student_output = $this->execute($student_dir, 1);
        $retval = strcmp($this->solution_output, $this->student_output);
        if ($retval === 0) {
            // Accept
            $this->status = 'AC';
        }
        else {
            // Wrong Answer
            $this->status = 'WA';
        }

        // Configure result that will response to client side
        $error_msg = null;
        $this->configureView($error_msg);

        return;

    }

    public function compile ($dir) {
        // Configure descriptor array
        $desc = array (
                0 => array ('pipe', 'r'), // STDIN for process
                1 => array ('pipe', 'w'), // STDOUT for process
                2 => array ('pipe', 'w') // STDERR for process
        );

        // Configure compilation command
        $cmd = 'javac -d ' . $dir . ' ';
        $source = glob($dir . '/*');
        foreach ($source as $key => $value) {
            $cmd .= $value . ' ';
        }

        // Create compilation process
        $process = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes);

        // Close STDIN pipe
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        // Get output of STDERR pipe
        $error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

        // Close STDOUT and STDERR pipe
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);

        // Close process
        proc_close($process);

        return $error;
    }

    public function execute ($dir, $pipe_id) {
        // Configure descriptor array
        $desc = array (
                0 => array ('pipe', 'r'), // STDIN for process
                1 => array ('pipe', 'w'), // STDOUT for process
                2 => array ('pipe', 'w') // STDERR for process
        );

        // Configure execution command
        $cmd = 'exec java -classpath ' . $dir . ' ';
            $last_pos = strrpos($this->main, '.java');
            $classname = substr($this->main, 0, $last_pos);
            $cmd .= $classname;

        // Create execution process
        $process = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes);

        // Get pid of execution process
        $process_status = proc_get_status($process);
        $pid = $process_status['pid'];  

        // Close STDIN pipe
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        // Wait seconds
        sleep(1);

        // Kill execution process
        posix_kill($pid, SIGTERM);

        // Get output of STDOUT or STDERR pipe
        $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[$pipe_id]);

        // Close STDOUT and STDERR pipe
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);

        return $output;
    }

    public function updateStatus () {
        $stmt = $this->hookup->prepare('UPDATE ' . $this->item . ' SET ' . $this->stu_account . '=\'' . $this->status . '\' WHERE subitem=\'' . $this->subitem . '\'');
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function configureView ($error_msg) {
        if (!is_null($error_msg)) {
            echo $error_msg;
        }
        else {
            $result = '';
            if ($this->status === 'WA') {
                $result = 'Wrong Answer';
            }
            if ($this->status === 'AC') {
                $result = 'Accept';
            }
            echo<<<EOF
<h1>$result</h1>
<div class='WHOSE_DIV'>
<img class='UP_DOWN_IMG' src='./tafree-svg/attention.svg'>
<div class='RES_DIV'>
<div class='SOL_DIV'>{$this->solution_output}</div>
<div class='STU_DIV'>{$this->student_output}</div>
</div>
</div>
EOF;

        }
        return;
    }

}

$judger = new Java_No_Input();

?>
```