# Get list of running processes with PHP

Tags: php

I want to get list of running processes for current user to assure if "file.php" is still running or not?
I'm using cPanel and web server is Litespeed.

Comment: You need to do some proper research and actually make some attempts before posting. We'll glad to help you with _specific_ issues with your _existing_ code. Currently, this question is _way_ too broad.

Comment: It is possible to do it. However the solution is dependent on Operating System. Linux or Windows or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need:

1. prepare the OS customized query to list running processes, on linux for example `ps faux | grep -i file.php`
2. execute PHP command [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or similar
3. parse returned values if needed to find the file running aka file.php

Comment: Answering question where the OP has shown zero research or effort of solving it themselves are usually frowned upon.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right and that's why I have not provided the solution but I shown a direction where to focus Ali could go to achieve what Ali wants. And the question is having tag PHP so I proposed PHP solution. Of course I could copy paste working code but I would not, since there was not demonstrated any effort to achieve the solution by Ali's own.

Answer (score 5):

```
$execstring='ps -f -u www-data 2>&1';
$output="";
exec($execstring, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Will give you something like this

```
Array (
    [0] => UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
    [1] => www-data  1587   790  0 14:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [2] => www-data  7336   790  0 17:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [3] => www-data 13426 16637  0 20:41 ?        00:00:00 sh -c ps -f -u www-data 2>&1
    [4] => www-data 13427 13426  0 20:41 ?        00:00:00 ps -f -u www-data
    [5] => www-data 13428 22299  0 20:41 ?        00:00:00 sh -c ps -f -u www-data 2>&1
    [6] => www-data 16412   790  0 15:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [7] => www-data 16637   790  0 15:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [8] => www-data 18977   790  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [9] => www-data 18978   790  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [10] => www-data 18979   790  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [11] => www-data 18981   790  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [12] => www-data 18983   790  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    [13] => www-data 19735     1  0 15:39 ?        00:00:00 php sql_runner.php
    [14] => www-data 22299     1 13 Mar23 ?        1-02:30:32 php scheduler.php
    [15] => www-data 22768   790  0 06:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start )
```

No you can filter/search with regex for your file.

Answer (score 1):

show tasks, redirect errors to NUL (hide errors)

```
exec("tasklist 2>NUL", $task_list);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($task_list);
```

Comment: Answering question where the OP has shown zero research or effort of solving it themselves are usually frowned upon.

Comment: In case it is not working for you, add `start /B`, i.e., `$task_list = array(); exec("start /B tasklist 2>NUL", $task_list);`. Source: [taskkill from PHP exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853625/taskkill-from-php-exec)

Answer (score 0):

First of You need to Just write `top` in command prompt.Then you can see all the list of service running as of now.

Go to you php code and use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to run this command.

Comment: Answering question where the OP has shown zero research or effort of solving it themselves are usually frowned upon.