# How to see a list of processes like in cpanel

Tags: php, terminal, process, exec, cpanel

cPanel has a feature in where if you click on the processes hyper link it shows you the PID, Process, CPU, MEM and an option to kill the process. How can I get a list of processes like in cPanel but using a PHP script. Specifically on shared hosting. I've tried googling around but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of running processes with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252047/get-list-of-running-processes-with-php)

Comment: @KenLee I tried that already, it didn't work. I just a list of something, but its not the same output like it is in cpanel. In cpanel it shows me what script is running like from `/public_html/test.php`

Comment: For these, you may use the output from apachetop

Comment: @KenLee I tried `ps -f -u myuser` (myuser is the user for my cpanel). or `top -u myuser` it just shows the command i just ran and bash or something called jailbait as the processes. Even though there is a script running

Comment: If your site is on a shared host, it' very likely that they don't allow you to run what ever system commands you like. You should contact them and see if it's even possible.